# Teensy tutorial not working

Tags: ros, embedded, tutorial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!  I'm having problems with the Teensy tutorial.  I've already worked through the linux tutorial with no problems.

Everything builds and loads properly, but when I start the ros2 serial agent, it appears to connect to the teensy and then crash out with no error messages.  When this happens the teensy jumps into the error_loop and will just blink away forever.

I'm running Arduino 1.8.13, Teensyduino 1.53 and using a Teensy 4.1 board. I've used both the v2.0.2-foxy micro_ros_arduino release as well as v1.0.0 with the same results. I've also tried it with Arduino 1.8.15 and get the same results.

Here's the output from the micro ros agent terminal:

```
milner@canterbury:~/arduino-1.8.13/hardware/teensy/avr$ ros2 run micro_ros_agent micro_ros_agent serial --dev /dev/ttyACM0
[1637094118.227826] info     | TermiosAgentLinux.cpp | init                     | Serial port not found. | device: /dev/ttyACM0, error 2, waiting for connection...
[1637094119.231427] info     | TermiosAgentLinux.cpp | init                     | Serial port not found. | device: /dev/ttyACM0, error 2, waiting for connection...
[1637094120.234235] info     | TermiosAgentLinux.cpp | init                     | Serial port not found. | device: /dev/ttyACM0, error 2, waiting for connection...
[1637094121.237957] info     | TermiosAgentLinux.cpp | init                     | Serial port not found. | device: /dev/ttyACM0, error 2, waiting for connection...
[1637094122.239907] info     | TermiosAgentLinux.cpp | init                     | Serial port not found. | device: /dev/ttyACM0, error 2, waiting for connection...
[1637094123.242296] info     | TermiosAgentLinux.cpp | init                     | Serial port not found. | device: /dev/ttyACM0, error 2, waiting for connection...
[1637094124.245006] info     | TermiosAgentLinux.cpp | init                     | Serial port not found. | device: /dev/ttyACM0, error 2, waiting for connection...
[1637094125.247322] info     | TermiosAgentLinux.cpp | init                     | Serial port not found. | device: /dev/ttyACM0, error 2, waiting for connection...
[1637094126.250484] info     | TermiosAgentLinux.cpp | init                     | Serial port not found. | device: /dev/ttyACM0, error 2, waiting for connection...
[1637094127.251737] info     | TermiosAgentLinux.cpp | init                     | Serial port not found. | device: /dev/ttyACM0, error 2, waiting for connection...
[1637094128.253653] info     | TermiosAgentLinux.cpp | init                     | Serial port not found. | device: /dev/ttyACM0, error 2, waiting for connection...
[1637094129.255863] info     | TermiosAgentLinux.cpp | init                     | Serial port not found. | device: /dev/ttyACM0, error 2, waiting for connection...
[1637094130.085380] info     | TermiosAgentLinux.cpp | init                     | running...             | fd: 3
[1637094130.085572] info     | Root.cpp           | set_verbose_level        | logger setup           | verbose_level: 4
[1637094131.908440] info     | Root.cpp           | create_client            | create                 | client_key: 0x49E910CB, session_id: 0x81
[1637094131.908500] info     | SessionManager.hpp | establish_session        | session established    | client_key: 0x49E910CB, address: 0
milner@canterbury:~/arduino-1.8.13/hardware/teensy/avr$
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/391079/teensy-tutorial-not-working/) by [Barty](https://answers.ros.org/users/89824/barty/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2021-11-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Could you open an issue in the micro_ros_arduino Github repo? It will be easier for us to track this problem there.

---

Originally posted by [Pablogs](https://answers.ros.org/users/62986/pablogs/) with karma: 443 on 2021-11-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Barty](https://answers.ros.org/users/89824/barty/) on 2021-11-17**:
Done, thanks!